# Why is upcasting automatic while downcasting is not?

Tags: java

So the question is self-explanatory. This seems like a weird exception or am I missing something bigger?
Why does java automatically upcast while not downcast?

```
interface I{
}
class C extends B implements I{
}
class B{
}

public class Car {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        I i = new C();
        C c = new C();
        B b = new C();

        i = c; // automatically adds i=(I)c
        b = c; // same

        // c = b; errors
        c = (C)b; //works if I add downcast
        // c = i; errors
        c = (C)i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because every apple is a fruit, but not every fruit is an apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple set algebra.

By definition, any C is a B.

You cannot conclude that any B is a C.

Comment: why not then do it at runtime. When you can see what object the reference references and then throw error if it is wrong. But true the compiler cannot conclude.

Comment: "why not then do it at runtime" because doing it at compile time is safer. Requiring an explicit cast forces you to think about the fact it could fail.

Comment: "Doing it at runtime" is exactly what happens when you write a cast expression.  The issue is not when it is done. but whether you have to ask for it to be done.  The reason you have to ask for it in Java is that Java is intended to be a type-safe language.

Answer (score 0):

Downcasting a subclass to its superclass makes the functionality of the subclass unavailable. Deliberately crippling the reference to a subclass is not something you would want in every case, so you have to be explicit about it.